# Intellij IDEA потребляет много памяти

Tags: java, intellij-idea, память

При работе с intellij idea потребляется очень много оперативной памяти, порядка 900-1200 мб, и из-за этого она постоянно зависает. Пробовал ставить 14-16 версии, но ничего не изменяется. Единственным исключением является intellij idea CE 15.0.2. Она потребляет около 300 мб и не зависает. Но мне нужна idea ultimate edition. Подскажите что делать, может кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой.

Comment: насколько я знаю подобные среды разработки всегда много потребляют, я сталкивался, но я просто начал писать notepad тогда, а запускать через консоль)) Возможно вышли более простые среды, но не уверен.

Comment: [Несколько советов по оптимизации Intellij IDEA](http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.ru/2008/02/10-tips-to-increase-intellij-idea.html).

Comment: 900-1200 - это вам еще повезло, при разработке на scala обычно ест больше 3000, но это зависит от размера проекта. Дело в том что данная IDE "очень умная" и это откладывает свой след на производительность. Я бы рекомендовал вам, если выбрать другую IDE возможности нет, обратится к руководству с вопросом о модернизации вашего рабочего места. 16 Гб оперативной памяти это минимум для комфортной работы с большим проектом на IDEA.

Comment: Нужно заexcludить ненужные файлы, находящиеся в проектной папке.

Comment: @post_zeew Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: вы моежте указать максимальное количество памяти, которая IDEA может использовать, в файлике `idea.vmoptions`

Comment: Мне помогло отключение плагинов. Причём, когда плагин требуется, среда сама предлагает его включить )

Comment: Вообще idle от jetbrains довольно требовательны к ресурсам, но можно поставить прогу для очистки оперативки по типу memreduct

Answer (score 1):

Я смог значительно оптимизировать её работу, отключив большое количество ненужных мне плагинов (например Spring или интеграция большинства серверов) . Если что-то потребуется, смогу обратно включить.

Answer (score -1):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/6746377604498-The-IDE-is-really-taking-up-too-much-memory - это единственное что мне помогло.
"Использование памяти в основном зависит от размера проектов. Возможно, вы захотите попробовать увеличить размер кучи в справке | Изменить настройки памяти. Если размер кучи слишком мал, GC будет часто запускаться с использованием центрального процессора и замедлять работу IDE."

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]